# Как проверить корректность арифметических знаков регулярным выражением?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Учу регулярные, почему этот код возвращает false?

```
$pol = '*';
$a = preg_match('[*\/\-+]',$pol);
var_dump($a);
```

Тут, почему-то, этот шаблон для данной строки работает прекрасно: http://www.rubular.com/
В чем проблема?

Суть регулярного, проверить на валидность арифметические знаки, которые приходят на входе.
Шаблон вроде верный, не пойму.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что PHP позволяет использовать множество парных и одиночных разделителей в регулярном выражении. Например все следующие регулярные выражения одинаковы:

```
[regex]
/regex/
(regex)
@regex@
#regex#
```

[Полный список разделителей](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.delimiters.php)

В Вашем случае квадратные кавычки это не символьный класс, а разделитель.

```
[*\/\-+]ui
```

равносильно

```
@*\/\-+@ui
```

Comment: Ну равносильно, и что? Почему false, если шаблон верен? Не понимаю.

Comment: Потому что регулярное выражение  

    *\/\-+  
Означает:  

Квантификатор * в начале регулярного выражения (ошибка)  
Знак слэша **/**  
Знак тире **-** один и более раз.

Comment: Шаблон #[*\/\-+]#ui - оказался рабочим. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Не за что :-) Только постарайтесь понять почему так происходило, иначе Ваш следующий вопрос будет, что за ошибка.  

> Unknown modifier [некая буква]